# How to increase a particular terms's weightage?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, text-mining

I am doing Text classification using LibSVM in Rapid Miner. I am using TFIDF values for processing documents. I need to Increase weightage of some terms in the documents(for eg. words in BOLD and CAPITAL letters). How can I achieve that using TFIDF values? If TFIDF is not the correct way, can anyone suggest some ways to achieve the result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to change feature weights? It is the goal of the model to determine the importance of each feature. The model will determine if capital or bold features are more or less important without you telling it.

Comment: @RyanVolpi I did not say she stole my money. **I** did not say she stole my money. I **did** not say she stole my money. I did **not** say she stole my money. I did not **say** she stole my money. I did not say **she** stole my money. I did not say she **stole** my money. I did not say she stole **my** money. I did not say she stole my **money**.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract bold or capitalized statements as another feature, prepending it with i.e. `.BOLD_` or `HEAVY_FEATURE_` before calculating the TD-IDF, and thus counting it as separately.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
However, I am doing that already. I want to know the way in which the TFIDF values should be changed for those BOLD_ or HEAVY_FEATURE_ terms.Is there any standard way by which I can increase TFIDF value? @Christopher